# Extract Maximum Count and then compare

Tags: sql, oracle10g, compare, max

```
SELECT c.student_name,COUNT(c.student_name)
FROM MEMBER c INNER JOIN NOMTABLE d ON  c.depart_name=d.depart_name  
WHERE (c.student_role = 'head actor' AND d.section='best head actor') OR (c.student_role = 'supporting actor' AND d.section='best supporting actor') OR 
      (c.student_role = 'head actress' AND d.section='best head actress') OR (c.student_role = 'supporting actress' AND d.section='best supporting actress')
GROUP BY c.student_name;
```

This is my query which will give the name of the student and number of times the student name appears. I want to extract the student name which has the maximum count and then I want to compare that student_name with the student_name in the Table Student and extract the student_name and date_of_birth of that student which had the most number of count.

I know I can do do Select * From( above query) Where rownum<=1 but then after that I'm not able to compare the student_name with the student_name in the student table.

Any help with this would he extremely helpful. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this with a subquery and `row_number()`:

```
SELECT s.*, cnt
FROM (SELECT c.student_name, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.student_name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MEMBER c INNER JOIN
           NOMTABLE d
           ON c.depart_name=  d.depart_name  
      WHERE (c.student_role = 'head actor' AND d.section='best head actor') OR
            (c.student_role = 'supporting actor' AND d.section='best supporting actor') OR 
            (c.student_role = 'head actress' AND d.section='best head actress') OR
            (c.student_role = 'supporting actress' AND d.section='best supporting actress')
      GROUP BY c.student_name
     ) cd JOIN
     students s
     on cd.student_name = s.student_name
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It throws an error at:
GROUP BY c.student_name
               *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: and I want to extract the date_of_birth and student_name from the student table.

Comment: @user3690321 . . . I cannot see why Oracle would produce that error; the subquery is essentially your query reformatted with an extra column.  If you just want two columns from the `students` table, then add those columns instead of `s.*` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT s.student_name,s.date_of_birth 
FROM student s
WHERE s.student_name = (SELECT c.student_name
                       FROM MEMBER c INNER JOIN NOMTABLE d ON  c.depart_name=d.depart_name  
                       WHERE (c.student_role = 'head actor' AND d.section='best head actor') 
                          OR (c.student_role = 'supporting actor' AND d.section='best supporting actor') 
                          OR (c.student_role = 'head actress' AND d.section='best head actress')              
                          OR (c.student_role = 'supporting actress' AND d.section='best supporting actress')
                      GROUP BY c.student_name
                      HAVING COUNT(c.student_name) = (SELECT COUNT(c.student_name) student_count
                                                      FROM MEMBER c INNER JOIN NOMTABLE d ON  c.depart_name=d.depart_name  
                                                      WHERE (c.student_role = 'head actor' AND d.section='best head actor') 
                                                      OR (c.student_role = 'supporting actor' AND d.section='best supporting actor') 
                                                      OR (c.student_role = 'head actress' AND d.section='best head actress')              
                                                      OR (c.student_role = 'supporting actress' AND d.section='best supporting actress') 
                                                      AND ROWNUM <=1 
                                                      GROUP BY c.student_name
                                                      ORDER  BY student_count DESC 
                                                      ));
```

Comment: that returns an error saying ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply

Comment: ORDER BY COUNT(c.student_name) DESC
*
ERROR at line 17:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I'm sorry but now it says that there is one more error. Thank for helping me though.

Comment: I cannot use LIMIT in oracle. It uses ROWNUM <=1

Comment: Sorry about that I thought it mysql my bad. Hope the code works now

Comment: ORDER BY COUNT(c.student_name) DESC * ERROR at line 17: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

It again throws this error. I checked and all the parenthesis are ending properly